Android Compose - In the login screen, login button leads to home page only AFTER second click (Note:user has signed up using Room DB already)
General overview

The application opens with a login Screen.
Login Screen has an option to signup at the bottom for new users.
User enters his details and when user toggles switch, it enables storage in offline mode(Room database).
The sign up is successfully done and user details are stored in Room database.Then app leads to Login Screen.
In login screen, user enters name and email and when user toggles switch(enables Room database), it leads to a check if user has signed up already and whether his details are in Room database.
But the PROBLEM is that now, a successfully registered user has to click Login button two times to navigate to home screen. On clicking once, the login button DOES NOT navigate to home screen.

Technical overview -

Login Screen is the UI.
Login Screen stores STATES like name,email,switch(using Room database or Api Call),a flag called hasAlreadySignedUpRoom to check if user who is trying to login has already signed up) etc.
Login Events stores ways user can interact with screen (Login Offline or Login Online) that are selected using the toggle switch.
Login View Model handles the login that happens after user chooses offline mode and then clicks Login button.
In login view model, we are setting the hasAlreadySignedUpRoom state to true if GetUser use case successfully gets a user from the Room database.
Class GetUserUseCase accepts a repository interface as input and returns Flow<User?>
Then back in Login Screen, if userData state is not null and if alreadySignedUpRoom state is true, we navigate to home screen.

Login Screen
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    navController:navController,
    loginViewModel:LoginViewModel
){

    val loginState = loginViewModel.state.value
    Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    color=MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ){

      Column( 
      modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
      verticalAlignment=Arrangement.Center,
      horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
      ){
         Text(
             fontSize=30.sp,
             text="Login Screen",
         )
         OutlinedTextField(
          value=loginState.name,
          onValueChange = {newName ->
            loginViewModel.onNameChange(newName)
          },
         label = {Text("Name")},
         )
         OutlinedTextField(
          value=loginState.email,
          onValueChange = {newEmail ->
            loginViewModel.onNameChange(newEmail)
          },
         label = {Text("Email")},
         )
         Switch(
           checked = loginState.useOffline.value,
           onCheckedChange = {
             loginState.useOffline.value=it
           }
         )
         Button(
           onClick={
              if(loginState.useOffline.value){
                  loginViewModel.onEvent(LoginEvent.LoginOffline)
              }  
           if(loginState.userData.value !=null){
               if(loginState.hasAlreadySignedUpRoom){
                   //go to home screen
                   navController.navigate(Screen.HomeScreen.route) 
               }else if(loginState.isValidEmail && !loginState.isEmptyFields){
                   //please sign up first
                   navController.navigate(Screen.SignupScreen.route)
               }else{
                 Log.d(TAG,"Login failed:Invalid email or empty field")
               }
           }){
               Text("Login")
           }
           TextButton(
               onClick = {
                 navController.navigate(Screen.SignupScreen.route)
               }
           )
              Text("Not registered? Please click here to signup")
           }
        }
     }
 }

Login State
data class LoginState(
   var name:String="",
   var email:String = "",
   var hasAlreadySignedUpRoom:Boolean = false,
   var isValidEmail:Boolean = false,
   var isEmptyFields:Boolean = false,
   var useOffline:MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false),//toggle switch
   var userData:User? = null,
)

Login event
sealed class LoginEvent{
  data object LoginOffline:LoginEvent() //uses room database
 }

Login view model
class LoginViewModel(
private userUseCases:UserUseCases,
):ViewModel(){

  private val _state = mutableStateof(LoginState())
  val state:State<LoginState> = _state

  fun onNameChange(newName:String){
    _state.value = _state.value.copy(name = newName)
  }
  fun onEmailChange(newEmail:String){
    _state.value = _state.value.copy(name = newEmail)
  }
  fun onEvent(event:LoginEvent){
    _state.value.isEmptyFields = checkIfEmpty(_state.value.name,_state.value.email)
    _state.value.isValidEmail = checkIfValidEmail(_state.value.email)

    when(event){
     is LoginEvent.LoginOffline ->{
      if(_state.value.isValidEmail && !_state.value.isEmptyFields){
       viewModelScope.launch{
         val offlineGetUser = userUsecases.getUser(_state.value.name,_state.value.email)
         //offlineGetUser is actually Flow<User?>
         offlineGetUser.collect{userData ->
           _state.value.userData = userData
           if(_state.value.userData!=null){
             _state.value = _state.value.copy(hasAlreadySignedupRoom=true)
           }else{
             Log.d("App","User not found in database.")
           }
         }
        }
       } else{
           Log.d("App","Invalid email or empty fields")
       }
      }
     }
    }
  }

** All use cases **
data class UserUseCases(
    val getUser:GetUserUseCase,
    //other use cases
)

** GetUserUseCase **
class GetUserUseCase(private val repository:UserRepository){
    //UserRepository is the interface 
    operator fun invoke(
      name:String,email:String
    ):Flow<User?>{
      return repository.get(name,email)
    }
}

